# Is SFML::View inverted-y axis standard? How to workaround it?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 2d, viewport, sfml

I have my objects in a world space using right-handed coordinates (x = right, y = up).

When I have to render them using SFML I'm having problems because I can't set up the View matrix in sf::View with a (y = up) matrix and then all is rendered y-flipped.

One solution I'm thinking is flipping the y-axis on every object before rendering it:

```
ObjectTransformMatrix * MatrixScale(1.0f,-1.0f)
```

But I think I will have to move the sf::View center to:

```
y = y - (view_size.y / 2.0)
```

Why sf::View is y-inverted ? Is my solution correct?

Comment: If you're interested in learning 2D transforms, [this HTML5 presentation](https://github.com/legends2k/2d-transforms-101/#2d-transforms-101) tries to get the idea across intuitively. It has animations to illustrate the effect of every transform and should be a good primer to understand the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why sf::View is y-inverted ?

Most graphics packages/libraries have their screen-space coordinate system with origin on the left-top corner, where X goes right and Y goes down. This is just a convention and SFML happens to pick this. Mind you, this isn't left or right-handed; that would depend on the third axes, if any. I'll take that the other coordinate system you're referring to is the conventional mathematical coordinate system.

> flipping the y-axis on every object before rendering it

Don't do this! You've a world defined to your convenience. Why change that when you can change the camera (`sf::View`) transform which will be implicitly applied to all rendered objects internally. From [the documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1View.php#details):

> sf::View defines a camera in the 2D scene.
>
> This is a very powerful concept: you can scroll, rotate or zoom the entire scene without altering the way that your drawable objects are drawn.
>   [...]
>   To apply a view, you have to assign it to the render target. Then, every objects drawn in this render target will be affected by the view until you use another view.

Essentially you would be setting the below derived matrix as the camera's transform but through the functions exposed via `sf::View`.

> Is my solution correct?

Partly right, you've guessed the rest. Flipping the axes is only part of the solution, you should also translate the origin to the right position. What you need is M<sub>m→s</sub> where *m* is the math space and *s* is the screen space. To find that you need to transform the screen space coordinate system to align with the math coordinate system. Since the scales are the same in both coordinate systems, we can use the values of width W and height H (originally from the screen space) as-is.

We've this:

```
              S--->---- W ---------+
              |                    |
              v                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |
              |                    H
              |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              ^                    |
              |                    |
              M--->----------------+
```

When we do S<sub>1, −1</sub> i.e. scale X-axis by 1 and Y-axis by −1 (flip Y), we have

```
              ^
              |
              S--->---- W ---------+
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |
              |                    H
              |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              ^                    |
              |                    |
              M--->----------------+
```

This new system is no longer S since its Y is flipped; lets call it S'. Now we've to translate (move) its origin to reach M. Since we're transforming coordinate systems, and not points, we've to do it with respect to S', the transformed intermediate coordinate system and not S.

We do T<sub>0, -H</sub> i.e. move H units along negative Y. We will end up with

```
              +-------- W ---------+
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              |
              |                    H
              |
              |                    |
              |                    |
              ^                    |
              |                    |
              O--->----------------+

where both M and S are at O.
```

We've to concatenate S and T to get the final M<sub>m→s</sub>. Since we're transforming coordinate systems, and not points, we've to post-multiply (assuming you're using column-vector convention).

> M<sub>m→s</sub> = S<sub>1, −1</sub> T<sub>0, -H</sub>

```
| 1  0  0 | | 1  0  0 |   | 1  0  0 |
| 0 −1  0 | | 0  1 −H | = | 0 −1  H |
| 0  0  1 | | 0  0  1 |   | 0  0  1 |
```

Say we've a screen that's 5×5 (for simplicity). Transform the point (1, 1) in the world space to screen space:

```
| 1  0  0 | |1|   |1|
| 0 −1  5 | |1| = |4|
| 0  0  1 | |1|   |1|
```

(1, 4) is the point's coordinates in screen space.

If you're following row-vector convention, you've to transpose the equation, M = AB i.e. M<sup>T</sup> = B<sup>T</sup> A<sup>T</sup>. That would give us

```
| 1  0  0 | | 1  0  0 |   | 1  0  0 |
| 0  1  0 | | 0 −1  0 | = | 0 −1  0 |
| 0 −H  1 | | 0  0  1 |   | 0  H  1 |
```

Comment: Thanks, but when you say "Don't do this! You've a world defined to your convenience. Why change that when you can change the camera (sf::View) transform". The problem is that I can't set up or don't know how to change the matrix inside sf::View using the current sf::View interface.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1View.php
 There, I can't change the internal matrix to do what you said, Scale and transform, or maybe I'm missing something?

The only way i can do it is using view.getTransform() and apply the transformations outside the class.. :( no?

Comment: You can use `sf::View::setCentre` for translate but it seems to lack a function to set the scale. Perhaps [`sf::RenderStates`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.2/classsf_1_1RenderStates.php) is what you want? It has a constructor that takes in a transform.

Comment: The sf::RenderStates is the Model matrix passed when rendering an object. Inside SFML, this matrix will be multiplied by the sf::View matrix (the View and Projection matrices).

So my solution involves getting the Model matrix and before I pass it to sf::RenderStates I Scale it by (1,-1) to change the y axes. Then this will be multiplied by the sf::View moved by (y = y - (view_size.y / 2.0))

SFML is lacking a basic functionality in sf::View isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does lack it. However, there seems to be an unadvertised, thus not future-proof (officially unsupported), way to set a negative scale. See [this post](http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=19173.msg138505#msg138505) from a thread on the exact same issue. Reading the whole thread would give you more insight.

Comment: From that post: "Use a view with a negative rectangle. Note that this is not an officially advertised feature, because thousands of users are fine with the coordinate system convention in graphics programming :) It works, but since it's not documented, you cannot rely on it to be future-proof -- strictly speaking at least."            I will try to set a negative rectangle.. but I think they should let the users of the library modify the view with freedom instead of saying that we should change our own defined space. For me this a -1 for SFML.

Comment: @FrameBuffer I do agree. I'd say you should raise a feature request/bug/wish to legalise this way of using the function so that in future people would not be affected by this issue. Even better is to allow just setting the view transform, do away with all the finer functions and let the developer do the math.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98158/discussion-between-framebuffer-and-legends2k).

Answer (score 4):

I just reversed the window height. I think that's it.

```
sf::View view = window.getDefaultView();
view.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, -WINDOW_HEIGHT); 
window.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way is simply to flip the y position coordinate before and after rendering a sprite to the window:

```
void draw(window)
{
    pos = sprite.getPos();
    sprite.setPos(pos.x, pos.y * -1);
    window.draw(sprite);
    sprite.setPos(pos.x, pos.y * -1);
}
```